# angular fullstack won't run

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gruntjs, angular-fullstack, yo

Hi I followed full install of npm, node and then angular fullstack as below, in centos 6 32 bit with all dependencies ruby etc updated,

then installed angular fullstack

```
# npm install -g yo grunt-cli bower generator-angular-fullstack
```

was root user in top directory i.e. cd .. won't take me any higher up hierarchy.
 then when running angular fullstack in project directory I get this,

**Got this consistent error message,**

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/root/.config/configstore/insight- yo.json'
 You don't have access to this file.
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:584:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:431:33)
at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:37:34)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/lib/cli.js:130:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

`
**please help!!**

ok so I'm new to this, have been tearing my hair out for 48 hours with this same problem, uninstall node reinstall, tried every single resource on web to fault find and no clue at all, my directory for project application is in /usr/angproj when I run # yo angular-fullstack dashbd it just crashes gives same error every time, I've followed all correct instructions from software developers to LETTER, no hope of fixing this, running Centos 32bit 6 with lastest node version 5, and all dependencies updated correctly, I created node as root user and am still root user when running fullstack in project directory.

PLEASE HELP!!! I really need angular fullstack for a project I'm doing and I'm falling at first hurdle! It looks like a great piece of software...Thanks for any advice or suggestions given.

For node install see next file

[node install log](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/iyt1ep0ryc7fy2g/AADr0X6ZXo9JB0QZ2LxrW2tLa?dl=0)

Comment: It seems like you're installing/running all of these commands as root. You should run them as your own user or as a user dedicated to running the server.

Comment: Hi Explosion Pills, many thanks for you advice, I am running them as root which is only user, through ssh of course and I run server alone...is it necessary to create a new user and use that to install node etc? or does it matter that I am running it all as root? in the code I mean is it expecting a user and I'm confusing it? thanks very much

Comment: Tried running node install using another user it just says I have to be root and so cannot install it that way

Comment: Dear explosion pills!, thank you so much, set up new user, installed node.js as root and then installed fullstack as user, it WORKED!!!! legend!!!  also was leaving install directory when creating new project directory when install is finished it puts me in directory with node_modules in it all working thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To be clear for any other newbies,  log in as root install all reccomended dependencies for node,  I can send links if unsure,

Now log in as su - your user name,  install angular fullpack from daft monks link on github,  once installed DO NOT LEAVE DIRECTORY INSTALL PLACES YOU IN.  Something like node_modules in /usr now create your first project directory,  cd into it,  run yo angular-fullpack yourprojectname and Enjoy!!